Matrix overloads margins
I have the following matrix
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                            & 0                             & \frac{1}{12}s_L(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L)                                                                                       & -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                           & 0                             & -\frac{1}{12} s_L(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L)                                                                                      \\
        0                                                                & \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L         & -\frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L                                                                                                                         & 0                                                                & -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L        & \frac{1}{2}y_{1}^0 \alpha s_L                                                                                                                         \\
        \frac{1}{12}s_L(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L)  & -\frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L & \frac{1}{24}s_L (12((x_{1}^0)^2 + (y_{1}^0)^2)\alpha + 4\sqrt{3}y_{1}^0\alpha s_L + \alpha s_L^2)         & -\frac{1}{12} s_L(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L) & \frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L  & \frac{1}{24} s_L (-12(x_{1}^0x_{2}^0 + y_{1}^0y_{2}^0)\alpha - 2\sqrt{3}(y_{1}^0 + y_{2}^0)\beta s_L + \alpha s_L^2) \\
        -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                           & 0                             & -\frac{1}{12} s_L(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L)                                                                                      & \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                            & 0                             & \frac{1}{12} s_L(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L)                                                                                       \\
        0                                                                & -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L        & \frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L                                                                                                                          & 0                                                                & \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L         & -\frac{1}{2}x_{2}^0\alpha s_L                                                                                                                         \\
        -\frac{1}{12} s_L(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L) & \frac{1}{2}x_{2}^0 \alpha s_L & \frac{1}{24} s_L (-12(x_{1}^0x_{2}^0 + y_{1}^0y_{2}^0)\alpha - 2\sqrt{3}(y_{1}^0 + y_{2}^0)\beta s_L + \alpha s_L^2) & \frac{1}{12} s_L(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L)  & -\frac{1}{2}x_{2}^0\alpha s_L & \frac{1}{24}s_L (12((x_{2}^0)^2 + (y_{2}^0)^2)\alpha + 4\sqrt{3}y_{1}^0\alpha s_L + \alpha s_L^2)         \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{document}

but it goes out of the margins.

How can I solve this?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

To keep yuor readers sane you should define variable names outside the matrix and then just list the matrix of these variable names. Then it will not be so wide and unreadable.

Una posible solución es redimensionarla, es decir
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{6}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  $\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                            & 0                             & \frac{1}{12}s_L\left(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L\right)                                                                                       & -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                           & 0                             & -\frac{1}{12} s_L\left(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L\right)                                                                                      \\
        0                                                                & \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L         & -\frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L                                                                                                                         & 0                                                                & -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L        & \frac{1}{2}y_{1}^0 \alpha s_L                                                                                                                         \\
        \frac{1}{12}s_L\left(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L\right)  & -\frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L & \frac{1}{24}s_L \left(12\left(\left(x_{1}^0\right)^2 + \left(y_{1}^0\right)^2\right)\alpha + 4\sqrt{3}y_{1}^0\alpha s_L + \alpha s_L^2\right)         & -\frac{1}{12} s_L\left(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L\right) & \frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L  & \frac{1}{24} s_L \left(-12\left(x_{1}^0x_{2}^0 + y_{1}^0y_{2}^0\right)\alpha - 2\sqrt{3}\left(y_{1}^0 + y_{2}^0\right)\beta s_L + \alpha s_L^2\right) \\
        -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                           & 0                             & -\frac{1}{12} s_L\left(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L\right)                                                                                      & \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L                                            & 0                             & \frac{1}{12} s_L\left(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L\right)                                                                                       \\
        0                                                                & -\frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L        & \frac{1}{2}x_{1}^0\alpha s_L                                                                                                                          & 0                                                                & \frac{1}{2}\alpha s_L         & -\frac{1}{2}x_{2}^0\alpha s_L                                                                                                                         \\
        -\frac{1}{12} s_L\left(6y_{1}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L\right) & \frac{1}{2}x_{2}^0 \alpha s_L & \frac{1}{24} s_L \left(-12\left(x_{1}^0x_{2}^0 + y_{1}^0y_{2}^0\right)\alpha - 2\sqrt{3}\left(y_{1}^0 + y_{2}^0\right)\beta s_L + \alpha s_L^2\right) & \frac{1}{12} s_L\left(6y_{2}^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L\right)  & -\frac{1}{2}x_{2}^0\alpha s_L & \frac{1}{24}s_L \left(12\left(\left(x_{2}^0\right)^2 + \left(y_{2}^0\right)^2\right)\alpha + 4\sqrt{3}y_{1}^0\alpha s_L + \alpha s_L^2\right)         \\
    \end{bmatrix}$}



Please note: This is an international site. The language is English. Please translate your answer. And please try to show complete code that can be copied and tested without need to extend or change it. This would help other users to find out, how to use your code and whether your solution could be relevant for their problem, too.

(Not only) my opinion: Scaling down text or math is not really recommended. The typeface suffers and so does readability. It should only be used as a last resort. It is better to either use a smaller font or to set it in landscape, for example, or to choose a different wrapping, if this is possible. Even using the margins can be a better solution.

which package is used?

I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of the output of this solution. The effect of \resizebox is a drastic reduction of the effective font size; compare the mathy material to the "Hello World" string above it. I believe it's fair to say that readers will not deem the result to acceptable.

Note that one should add \noindent instruction immediately before \resizebox{...}.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@baristocrona - Just out of idle curiosity: Why did you accept an answer that (a) is incomplete, (b) contains pointless instructions (such as \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{6}), and (c) produces output that is so tiny that your readers will find it to be just about undecipherable? (Compare the mathy part to the string "Hello World"...)

@Mico I ended up using that one on my paper. If it was possible accepting two, I'd definitely also accept yours.

@baristocrona - Thanks. Incidentally, should the 6x6 matrix be symmetric or not?

@Mico I wish the rigidity matrix was symmetric, but my model is not happy with that.

I suggest you replace some of the longer expressions with a_0, a_1, etc (feel free to use a different abbreviation method...) and provide a separate legend to list the meanings of the abbreviated terms. E.g.,

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Consider
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_0 & 0 & a_1 & -a_0 & 0 & a_3 \\
 0 & a_0 & -a_0 x_1^0 & 0 & -a_0 & a_0 y_1^0 \\
 a_1 & -a_0 x_1^0 & a_4 & a_3 & a_0 x_1^0 & a_5 \\
 -a_0 & 0 & a_3 & a_0 & 0 & a_3 \\
 0 & -a_0 & a_0 x_1^0 & 0 & a_0 & -a_0 x_2^0 \\
 -a_2 & a_0 x_2^0 & a_5 & a_3 & -a_0 x_2^0 & a_6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
where 
\begingroup
\addtolength{\jot}{2pt}
\begin{align*} 
a_0&=\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha s_L \\
a_1&=\tfrac{1}{12} s_L (6y_1^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\alpha s_L) \\
a_2&=\tfrac{1}{12} s_L (6y_1^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L) \\
a_3&=\tfrac{1}{12} s_L (6y_2^0\alpha + \sqrt{3}\beta s_L)\\
a_4&=\tfrac{1}{24} s_L [12((x_1^0)^2 + (y_1^0)^2)\alpha + 4\sqrt{3}y_1^0\alpha s_L + \alpha s_L^2] \\
a_5&=\tfrac{1}{24} s_L [-12(x_1^0x_2^0 + y_1^0y_2^0)\alpha - 2\sqrt{3}(y_1^0 + y_2^0)\beta s_L + \alpha s_L^2] \\
a_6&=\tfrac{1}{24} s_L [12((x_2^0)^2 + (y_2^0)^2)\alpha + 4\sqrt{3}y_1^0\alpha s_L + \alpha s_L^2]
\end{align*}
\endgroup

\end{document}


Incidentally, the 6x6 matrix is nearly, but not fully, symmetric. The cell pairs (1,6)/(6,1) and (2,6)/(6,2) break full symmetry. Is this impression correct?
